# How can i "stretch out" image from the container to the right side of screen?

Tags: html, css

I tried putting image-tag to wrapper with positioned absolute top 0, right 0. But in this case image-wrapper goes out from parent box. So do you have any ideas? And what is better to choose: img-tag or div with background-image?
[final result in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aDtr.jpg)

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.about__left, .about__right {
    width: 50%;
}
.about-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.about__left-text {
    width: 85%;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.about__left-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.about__right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    /* width: 950px;
    height: 600px;
    background-image: url('../images/about__pic.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; */
}
.about__right-pic {
    /* position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0; */
}
```

```html
<div class="about mb180">
            <div class="container about-wrapper">
                <div class="about__left">
                    <h2 class="about__left-title title">О нас</h2>
                    <p class="about__left-text text">Командор - официальный дистрибьютор и эксклюзивный представитель международной марки Komandor в России. 25 лет на рынке, представительства в более, чем 11 странах мира, в России работает более 400 торговых точек и 40 сертифицированных производств</p>
                </div>
                
                <div class="about__right">
                    <img class="about__right-pic" src="images/about__pic.png" alt="pic">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `img` tags always try to display as their original sizes.

You can add this rule to restrict its width:

```css
max-width: 100%
```

Or if you prefer it always fill the entire width of its parent. Add this one instead:

```css
width: 100%;
```

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.about__left, .about__right {
    width: 50%;
}
.about-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}
.about__left-text {
    width: 85%;
    line-height: 35px;
}
.about__left-title {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}
.about__right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.about__right-pic {
    /* added */
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="about mb180">
    <div class="container about-wrapper">
        <div class="about__left">
            <h2 class="about__left-title title">О нас</h2>
            <p class="about__left-text text">Командор - официальный дистрибьютор и эксклюзивный представитель международной марки Komandor в России. 25 лет на рынке, представительства в более, чем 11 странах мира, в России работает более 400 торговых точек и 40 сертифицированных производств</p>
        </div>

        <div class="about__right">
            <img class="about__right-pic" src="https://picsum.photos/640/480" alt="pic">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow:hidden;` to .container and see.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or add this new css rule;

```
.about__right-pic,
.about__right img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are not setting any width and height to image so it takes place as its original width.

So add width to   .about_right-pic and try it again.